# Selecting multiple random days from datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, datepicker

How do i select multiple dates in DatePicker for yii?

1. Select random multiple days from calander and save it

I want to select different days like 10th feb, 12th feb, 18th feb, 16th feb etc.. User will select multiple days, how do i do that?

Comment: which datepicker are you using?

Comment: I have this one in my complete project http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this datepicker and use it as your requirements. This is bit popular in multiple selecting dates. Please go through the link :: [multidatespickr example](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)